# Передача сообщения через класс Socket между клиентом и сервером

Tags: c#

Есть массив кнопок, которые расположены на форме и с которыми происходят определенные действия через метод, как мне передать в байтовый массив информацию об этих кнопках, то есть передавать координаты нажатия кнопки от клиента к серверу   и наоборот, что бы отображался ход у каждого из игроков на поле (игра крестики-нолики по сети)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно это делается следующим образом.

Для начала, программу нужно разделить на слои: UI, который занимается только отображением, модель, которая занимается вычислениями, общением по сети, сериализацией и тому подобными невидимыми вещами, и промежуточный слой — контроллер или вью-модель, в зависимости от вашего выбора способа деления на слои (MVC или MVVM).

Итак, проблема уходит на уровень модели.

Теперь, в модели вам нужно соединение с сервером и какой-то протокол передачи информации. Например, вы можете определить объект «Ход», и передавать его на сервер (а также получать) в сериализованном виде. Для общения с сервером я бы посоветовал [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`TcpListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx), сокет — чересчур низкоуровневая штука. Для сериализации простого класса наверное проще всего написать свой велосипед или воспользоваться [готовым `BinaryFormatter`'ом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Если ваша программа простая, вы можете упростить себе начальную разработку, соединив в один несколько слоёв, но это обычно затрудняет разработку в будущем.

---

С `TcpListener`'ом передача набора байт тривиальна. Вы получаете `NetworkStream`, запись выглядит просто как

```
await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Для чтения известного размера данных нужно немного более сложный код:

```
async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(Stream stream, int nBytesExact)
{
    var buf = new byte[nBytesExact];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nBytesExact)
    {
        var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nBytesExact - readpos);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        readpos += actuallyRead;
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию, но у меня стоит задача реализация только через сокет

Comment: Вы программист, вы должны сами выбирать себе подходящий инструмент. Тот, кто ставил задачу, застрял в каменном веке. Переубедите его, это ваша задача как хорошего программиста.

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен, но это учебное учреждения и если преподавателю принести правильное решения но решенное не так как он требовал то он его просто не примет

Comment: @Vitaliy: Понимаю, конечно. В принципе, можно `NetworkStream` надеть и на `Socket`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8fz0y3(v=vs.110).aspx. Но будет немного сложнее.

Comment: @Vitaliy: Вот вам мини-пример с сокетом: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8990010/276994 (но лучше используйте async-функции, чтобы не подвисало)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться.