# Соединение разрывается при простое

Tags: c#, tcp

Подключаюсь, сначала нормальное общение, как только немного простой (отсутствие активности) на клиенте, то получаю принудительный разрыв соединения. Но тоже не сразу, а после того как попытаюсь что-нибудь запросить у сервера.
По логам вижу что запрос от клиента до сервера дошел и тот на него ответил, но на клиенте ничего нет.
Проблема имеет характер только на реальном хостинге, а на домашней машине все в порядке.

При необходимости могу предоставить код, а так я [использую этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659053).

**Код клиента**.

```
public async Task Send(Packet message)
{
    var buffer = message?.ToBytes();
    if (buffer?.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length).ToList();
            bytes.AddRange(buffer);
            await _stream.WriteAsync(bytes.ToArray(), 0, bytes.Count);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Connection close");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}

private async Task<byte[]> ReceiveTask(int byteCount)
{
    var buffer = new byte[byteCount];
    var pos = 0;
    while (pos < byteCount)
    {
        var count = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, pos, buffer.Length - pos);
        if (count == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        pos += count;
    }
    return buffer;
}

public async void Receive()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var packetLenBytes = await ReceiveTask(4);
            var packetlen = BitConverter.ToInt32(packetLenBytes, 0);
            if (packetlen > MaxLenSize && packetlen < 0) break;
            var data = await ReceiveTask(packetlen);
            RaiseEventMessegaReceive(data);
        }
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
    finally
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Код на сервере**:

```
public ClientTcp(TcpClient client, ServerTcp serverTcp)
{
    _client = client;
    _serverTcp = serverTcp;
    _serverTcp.ClientAdd(this);
    _stream = client.GetStream();
    _client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
    Address = ((IPEndPoint)_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
    Port = ((IPEndPoint)_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
    GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Program.ClientLogger.Info($"Client from {Address}:{Port} connect.");

    Task.Run(Receive);
}


public async Task Send(Packet message)
{
    if (message == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

    Program.CommandLogger.Info($"Sent: {message.Command} to {Address}:{Port}");
    var buffer = message.ToBytes();
    if (buffer.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            await _stream.WriteAsync(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}

private async Task<byte[]> ReceiveTask(int byteCount)
{
    var buffer = new byte[byteCount];
    var pos = 0;
    while (pos < byteCount)
    {
        var count = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, pos, buffer.Length - pos);
        if (count == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        pos += count;
    }
    return buffer;
}

private async Task Receive()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var packetLenBytes = await ReceiveTask(4);
            var packetlen = BitConverter.ToInt32(packetLenBytes, 0);
            if (packetlen > MaxLenSize)
                break;
            var data = await ReceiveTask(packetlen);
            RaiseEventMessegaReceive(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignore
    }
    finally
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: приведи твой код

Comment: Сколько длится ваше "немного"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov сейчас это произошло через 4 минут.

Comment: `catch (Exception) { // ignore }` - ай-ай-ай

Comment: Откройте для себя NLog

Comment: @PavelMayorov В защиту своего кода скажу, что Nlog использую.
Игнорирование исключения было задумано специально, чтобы не захламлять лог частыми отключениями и подключениями.
WireShark еще не пробовал, как попробую отпишусь дополнительно.

Comment: @adrug имеет смысл выяснить как выглядит это самое "частое отключение" и выключить вывод в лог именно его

Comment: @adrug а общий обработчик нужно держать включенным всегда

Comment: @adrug кстати, если вы используете NLog - имеет смысл вместо удаления вывода в лог сменить уровень на Trace, а уже в конфиг-файле его выключить. Тогда при таких расследованиях как сейчас можно его будет включить обратно не меняя кода.

Comment: @PavelMayorov поясните пожалуйста, не совсем понял:
"а общий обработчик нужно держать включенным всегда"

Comment: @adrug Если свалится внезапный BrokenHandsException - очень важно чтобы он попал в лог, иначе вы так и будете думать что это обычное отключение клиента.

Comment: @PavelMayorov проверил через WireShark. Сервер клиента считает живым и отправляет ему по таймеру данные, но шарк ничего не ловит.

Comment: @adrug значит, это точно сетевая проблема. У вас случайно не мобильный интернет?

Comment: @PavelMayorov проводной, но сижу я через Wifi.

Comment: @adrug тогда странно, не должно быть у проводного инета такого маленького времени жизни соединения...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобные проблемы могут возникать из-за межсетевых экранов, отслеживающих состояние соединения. Обычно они используются для реализации PNAT (трансляции сетевых адресов). Этой трансляцией может заниматься ваш роутер или провайдер. Проверьте IP-адрес компьютера, где запущен клиент: если он из подсетей 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 или 192.168.0.0/16 (так называемые диапазоны серых адресов) - значит, где-то NAT точно есть.

Но даже если вы используете белый IP - это еще не означает, что между клиентом и сервером нет межсетевого экрана.

Проблема таких промежуточных устройств - в том, что при простое соединения они "забывают" про него, после чего начинают блокировать входящие пакеты. Транслятор адресов это делает просто потому что не знает куда пакет направить, другие межсетевые экраны - в приступе паранойи :-)

Для того, чтобы избежать подобного поведения, следует ввести в протокол пустую команду ("пинг"), которую бы клиент периодически отправлял серверу для поддержки соединения в активном состоянии. Интервал передачи следует сделать настраиваемым, поскольку необходимая частота служебных пакетов зависит от настроек сетевого оборудования.

Альтернативный вариант - включить на сокете [настройку](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e160993d(v=vs.110).aspx) `KeepAlive`. Но по умолчанию интервал отправки служебных пустых пакетов системой - 2 часа, а потому нельзя особо надеяться на него.

Возможно также, что все эти соображения тут ни при чем - а просто вас в коде есть ошибка. Используйте Wireshark чтобы точно убедиться что ответ от сервера до вас не доходит.

Comment: Какая-то напасть. 
Настраивал KeepAliveValue по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169170/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-keep-alive-socket-checking-in-net/170296#170296) на 25 секунд, то ли еще нужно что-то добавить, но мне не помогло.
Также попробовал в ручную отправку пустых запросов раз в 30 секунд и в итоге соединение теперь не разрывается.

Comment: @adrug а какое отношение та ссылка имеет к периоду системных Keep Alive?

Comment: Вы сказали использовать механизм KeepAlive, но у него интервал 2 часа. Я попытался уменьшить его под свои нужны.