# Управление Serial Port rs485 - протокол modbus rtu

Tags: c#, wpf, modbus

Появилась необходимость написать приложение которое может общаться с некоторым устройством, оно имеет интерфейс rs485 работает по протоколу modbus rtu. Честно признаюсь опыта работы с регистрами, байтами нет. Поэтому прошу помощи.

Инженер железки кинул описание:

> BaudRate = 9600;  DataBits = 8; Parity = None; StopBits = Two;
>
> Устройство поставляется с установленным адресом 0х01 . Регистры
>   значения веса находятся в регистрах по адресу 0000h и 0001h .
>
> Пример чтения регистров : запрос - 01 03 00 00 00 02 C4 0B
>
> Где: Первый байт - номер устройства (адрес) Второй байт - номер
>   функции (03 = чтение регистров) Третий и четвертый - адрес начала
>   регистров (0000) Пятый и шестой - количество регистров (0002)
>   Последние два байта - контрольная сумма.
>
> ответ - 01 03 04 00 00 00 4C FB C6
>
> Где: Первый и второй байты повторяют запрос Третий байт - количество
>   байт данных (4 байта) Данные: 00 00 00 4C = 76 у.е. Последние два
>   байта - контрольная сумма.

Раз в 60 мс, приложение должно опрашивать устройство и возвращать значение на экран.
Как лучше реализовать? Запрос в отдельном потоке? Или смысла нет?

1. Мне нужно отправить команду на чтение веса, я правильно понимаю, мне нужно сделать так?

   ```
   serial = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
   serial.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
   serial.Parity = Parity.None;
   serial.DataBits = 8;
   serial.StopBits = StopBits.Two;            
   serial.Open();
   serial.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xC4, 0x0B }, 0, 8);
   serial.Close();
   ```
2. Прочитать ответ с устройства. Здесь больше мне не понятно. Как получить ответ и как его интерпретировать? распарсить байты

Comment: Принимать просто, читаете нужное количество байт из `Stream`'а. А вот уж как их интерпретировать — это вопрос к вам, а не к нам.

Comment: Спасибо. С интерпретированием погорячился..конечно не  сюда. по поводу Stream не пойму. Можете пример привести? А по поводу отправки, я правильно отправляю ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для чтения воспользуйтесь таким методом:

```
byte[] ReadExact(Stream s, int nbytes)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += s.Read(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
    return buf;
}
```

(Или используйте async-вариант [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535655/10105).)

И читайте из потока:

```
byte[] response = ReadExact(serial.BaseStream, 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня железа нет для проверки, так что код только для примера как можно прочитать.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serial = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
            serial.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            serial.Parity = Parity.None;
            serial.DataBits = 8;
            serial.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
            serial.Open();
            serial.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xC4, 0x0B }, 0, 8);
            ReadReponse(serial);
            serial.Close();
        }

        static void ReadReponse(SerialPort serial)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Чтение ответа...");

            var byteBuffer = GetData(serial);
            CheckResponse(byteBuffer);

            var firstRegValue = CreateRegValue(byteBuffer[3], byteBuffer[4]);
            Console.WriteLine(firstRegValue);

            var secondRegValue = CreateRegValue(byteBuffer[5], byteBuffer[6]);
            Console.WriteLine(secondRegValue);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static byte[] GetData(SerialPort serial)
        {
            int offset = 0;
            var byteBuffer = new byte[9];
            while (offset < 9) {
                offset += serial.Read(byteBuffer, offset, byteBuffer.Length - offset);
            }

            return byteBuffer;
        }

        static void CheckResponse(byte[] respones)
        {
            // здесь проверяем контрольную сумму, номер железки и номер функции
        }

        static Int16 CreateRegValue(byte hiByte, byte lowByte)
        {
            return (Int16)(hiByte << 8 | lowByte);
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:**
В примере я использую простой Read, но есть событие [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) через которое можно читать асинхронно. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754694/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-a-serial-port-using-net-framework?noredirect=1&lq=1) есть советы.

Comment: `serial.Read` неправильно, т. к. это может прочитать лишь часть сообщения. Нужно читать в цикле до победного.

Comment: @VladD согласен, исправлено