# Вывод ответа с устройства по протоколу modbus RTU C#

Tags: c#, modbus

Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо считывать данные с устройств по протоколу modbus. Я не могу понять, как получить ответ от устройства.

Я вызываю свою функцию, но как мне получить данные с устройства? Может, кто-то может помочь.

P.S. Готовые библиотеки типа nmodbus, я использовал, но хочу разобраться как это сделать самому.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Connection comPort = new Connection("COM6", 19200, 8);
        //comPort.readHoldingCom(2, 0x600, 16);
        //comPort.writeHoldingCom(2, 0x44E, 0x0100);

        //Connection portTCP = new Connection("192.168.127.12", 4001);
        //portTCP.readHoldingTcp(2, 0x600, 16);
        var serial = new SerialPort("COM6", 19200);
        serial.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serial.Parity = Parity.None;
        serial.DataBits = 8;
        serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        serial.Open();

        serial.Write(ReadHoldingRegister(2, 1024, 16), 0, 8);
        ReadReponse(serial);

        serial.Close();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void ReadReponse(SerialPort serial)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Чтение ответа...");

        var byteBuffer = GetData(serial);

        var firstRegValue = CreateRegValue(byteBuffer[3], byteBuffer[4]);
        Console.WriteLine(firstRegValue);

        var secondRegValue = CreateRegValue(byteBuffer[5], byteBuffer[6]);
        Console.WriteLine(secondRegValue);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static Int16 CreateRegValue(byte hiByte, byte lowByte)
    {
        return (Int16)(hiByte << 8 | lowByte);
    }

    static byte[] GetData(SerialPort serial)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        var byteBuffer = new byte[9];
        while (offset < 9)
        {
            offset += serial.Read(ReadHoldingRegister(2, 1024, 16), 0, 8);
        }

        return byteBuffer;
    }

    #region Function 3
    public static byte[] ReadHoldingRegister(int id, int startAddress, int length)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        byte High, Low;

        data[0] = Convert.ToByte(id);
        data[1] = Convert.ToByte(3);

        byte[] _adr = BitConverter.GetBytes(startAddress - 1);

        data[2] = _adr[1];
        data[3] = _adr[0];

        byte[] _length = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);

        data[4] = _length[1];
        data[5] = _length[0];

        myCRC(data, 6, out High, out Low);

        data[6] = Low;
        data[7] = High;

        return data;
    }
    #endregion

    #region CRC
    public static void myCRC(byte[] message, int length, out byte CRCHigh, out byte CRCLow)
    {
        ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ message[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((CRCFull & 0x0001) == 0)
                    CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull >> 1);
                else
                {
                    CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
                }
            }
        }
        CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
        CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Вообще, у Вас нет подписки на приходящие данные из порта.
Как минимум, нужно воспользоваться событием SerialPort.DataReceived (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx), и добавить обработчик данного события. Конкретно про протокол, команды и все такое можно почитать вот тут - https://ipc2u.ru/articles/prostye-resheniya/modbus-rtu/

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov я добавил  SerialPort.DataReceived, но все-равно вывести ничего не получается

Comment: готовый [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789467/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-serial-port-rs485-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-modbus-rtu)